# Jquery Crossed fade animation the simple way

Tags: jquery

I am working on a rotating banner. Everything works great but I am unable to get clean animations with when the banner rotates.

I am fairly new at jQuery so I am a bit newbish to say the least.

ok so the banner uses the following code to fade out and fade in a new image

```
$(image).fadeOut(100);
$(image).fadeIn(100);
```

This fades out and go white for a second and then the new image fades in.

I am sure there is a way to do this seamlessly but I just can't seem to grasp the concept here. I do not want to go to a plugin since this banner is really simple and I don't want to complicate things at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(image).fadeOut(100, function(){ 
    $(this).fadeIn(100); 
});
```

Use the callback of the fadeOut animation call to run the new fade in so the proper sequence is followed.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: I have tried this and this gives the same effect has what I am doing but has a extra flashing like effect as well.

Comment: @JustinPGreer See Rich's answer then. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

- Place one image on top of the other using absolute positioning
- Fade the top image out
- Change the source of the hidden top image to the bottom image
- Change the opacity of the top image to 100%

You can do this using jQuery animate for old browsers, and CSS transitions for normal ones - this way it will look smooth on iOS due to hardware acceleration, rather than jerky and horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Good Example of cross-fading if that is exactly what you are looking for [Here](http://css.dzone.com/news/jquery-image-cross-fade-transi)

Answer (score -1):

I assume your image has an id?

if so, you should change

```
$(image).fadeOut(100);
$(image).fadeIn(100);
```

to

```
$("#image").fadeOut(100);
$("#image").fadeIn(100);
```

the '#' tells the script to look at an element with the id image

Comment: Yea all images have a class that it attaches to. The rotating feature works but it has a flash like effect. I am trying to get the images to cross fade or something on those lines